# Помогите с ошибкой после компиляции py в exe (cx_Freeze)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

работаю в python 3.6.0 компилирую через cx_Freeze

Помогите пожалуйста уже очень давно ищу ответ на вот эту ошибку:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
>   ImportError: bad magic number in ‘encodings’: b'3\r\r\n'
>
> Current thread 0x00003574 (most recent call first):

не знаю что делать. раньше компилировал на python 3.4.4 и все было норм.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Откуда вы взяли такие версии? Самая последняя выпущенная версия - 3.6

Comment: Просто попробуйте более раннюю версию

Comment: Сори пацаны ошибся с версиями 3.6.0 и 3.4.4

Comment: Ругается на то, что не может загрузить кодек файловой системы. Ошибка: неверное "магическое число" в декодировке.
Посмотрите, что вы написали в начале файла (типа #-*- coding: utf8 -*-), или может вы не сохранили файл в utf8.